# Extracting Characters from String in Java

Tags: java, string, char

I am beginner to programming and running this code in Java

```
 String demo = "This is first string";
 char ch[]= demo.toCharArray();
 System.out.println(ch);
```

Output:

```
 This is first string
```

while,

```
 System.out.println("result is "+ch);
```

Output:- (Showing hashcode related to object memory)

```
 result is: someHashcode
```

1) Why do we have different output for both of them(Above mentioned code)? What actually happening over here.

And On other hand

```
 int num[]={1,2,3,4};
 System.out.println(num);
```

output:-

```
 somehashcode
```

2) This is not working as in char array case(like first mentioned code above) and give output as hashcode ,Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PrintStream` has overloaded `println` method for character array. When you pass character array to it, it prints the characters from it as if it was a String.

Hovewer when you pass array of other types, it treats it as object -- its `toString()` representation is printed out.

And in this example:

```
System.out.println("result is "+ch);
```

You are appending the array to a string literal, therefore `toString` form of `ch` will be appended to the literal which is why you don't get your expected result.

Comment: Just to be clear. `out` is static variable in `System` class of type `PrintStream`. So it has access to `println(String)` and `println(char[])` methods (among many others). Now `PrintStream#print(char[])` method will print all characters from passed array, but in case of `"result is "+ch` this code will be converted into a `String`, not `char[]` because when you are using `+` and one of operand is String and other is not, compler  will concatenate these values by using StringBuilder which for non-String objects is appending results of `toString()` method (which for arrays returns type@hexhash.